# Range manual asks for 40A while label states 26.5A

Tags: range

Running a new 8/3 Wire (75') for my Samsung dual fuel Range. Was about to use a 40A circuit breaker, but the difference between the installation manual (40A) and the label on the appliance (26.5) makes me wonder.

Is it ok to have what's looks like an oversize breaker in the box?

Many thanks!

Comment: What model is this range? It seems weird that they'd call out a 40A circuit when a 30A would actually suffice if you run the 220.55 demand factor calculations...

Comment: Is the range commonly installed with an oven also?

Comment: The manual calls for a 40-A breaker so use it. Someday someone may want to install an all electric range and you will have the conductor and breaker to do it.

Comment: Also I have never heard of dual-”fuel” meaning electric+gas, usually it means methane/propane and the electric is just for the clock and igniter.  Just to sanity check, are you sure it's 26.5A and not 26.5VA or 26.5W?

Comment: The breaker is to protect the wiring. If your wiring is suitable for 40 amp it is irrelevant if the appliance could do with a smaller breaker.

Comment: @Harper just google "Samsung Dual Fuel Range"... It's really a thing.  We considered it during a remodel, but getting gas to the location didn't work out as easily as we thought.

Comment: I don’t know this for fact: but I suspect the answer is that it’s set up for a 40amp circuit because in existing kitchens that is what will be feeding the range opening.

Comment: @Tyson mental note: stop being surprised by anything from Korea (that's a compliment).  I agree, for one thing 40/50A is what will be in most homes (for most versatility use 6/3 wire) and for another thing, it isn't uncommon to see a component range and component oven share that 40 or 50.  The 26 gives headroom for an oven.

Comment: @Harper it’s a single unit slide in. Gas cooktop, electric oven.

Comment: Yes, Gas burners and electric oven. I'll therefore install a 40A breaker. I was afraid a "too strong" breaker could be problematic.

Answer (score 2):

A 40 amp breaker is not oversized for #8 wire. It is just right.

The National Electrical Code requires a minimum of a 40 amp circuit for ranges of 8 3/4 KW or greater.

Here is the pertinent part of the Code:

> **210.19(A)(3) Household Ranges and Cooking Appliances.**  Branch-circuit conductors supplying household ranges, wall-mounted ovens, counter-mounted cooking units, and other household cooking appliances shall have an ampacity not less than the rating of the branch circuit and not less than the maximum load to be served. For ranges of 8 3∕4 kW or more rating, the minimum branch-circuit rating shall be 40 amperes.

The label on your range would indicate it only draws 6.3KW which could be fed by a 30 amp circuit but if the manufacturer is recommending a 40 amp circuit you should follow that recommendation.

Besides the next range you buy may need more power.